# How can I have a network connection after uninstalling network manager?

Tags: internet, network-manager, dnsmasq

I removed dnsmasq-base with `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq-base`

then I tried to install `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`

After executing the first command network manager is disabled and I am not more connected to any network, so the second command execution failed due to network error.

Now I am wondering how to connect to any network , since network manager is disabled, I am not able to connect to any network.

Comment: @rabbit try live cd and download the package and installed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [this link](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dnsmasq/), download the correct `.deb` on another computer, save it to a USB drive, and install it using the Software Center.